# Regex any alphanumeric characters except certain ones and max sequence of digits

Tags: java, regex

Looking for regex that will find a field that is 12 alphanumberic characters long, but can not have upper or lower case 'O' or 'I'. Also it can not have special characters. And cannot have a sequence of 9 or more numbers in a row.  I know I can do ^[a-hj-np-zA-HJ-NP-Z0-9]{12}$ but I don't know how to not match on having 9 or more numbers in a row.

`12345678A903`  should be valid.
`abcdefghj34y`  should be valid.
`123456789a34`  should be invalid
`abc987654321`  should be invalid

Comment: Add `(?!.*[0-9]{9})` after `^`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?i)^(?!.*\d{9})[A-HJ-NP-Z0-9]{12}$
```

Where:

- `(?i)`                # case insensitive
- `^`                   # beginning of line
- `(?!.*\d{9})`         # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't 9+ consecutive digits
- `[A-HJ-NP-Z0-9]{12}`  # 12 alphanumerics except I and O (because of (?i) it matches also lowercase letters)
- `$`                   # end of line

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/qxOhSq/1)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
^(?!.*?\d{9,})[a-hj-np-zA-HJ-NP-Z0-9]{12}$
```

As seen **[here](https://regex101.com/r/qXo0ao/1)**

## Explanation:

`(?!.*?\d{9,})` is a negative lookahead in regex, which signifies that the match should NOT be followed by zero-or-more characters and 9 or more digits

You can find out more about negative lookaheads here: [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could try such pattern `^(?!.*[oOiI])(?!.*\d{9,})[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$`

Explanation:

`^` - match beginning of the string

`(?!.*[oOiI])` - negative lookahead: assert that in the string there is not any of the characters: `oOiI`

`(?!.*\d{9,})` - negative lookahead: assert that in the string there is not 9 or more consecutive digits

`[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}` - match 12 of alphanumeric characters

`$` - match end of the string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6W4rJl/2)